# How to process files serially in cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have written a cloud storage trigger based cloud function. I have 10-15 files landing at 5 secs interval in cloud bucket which loads data into a bigquery table(truncate and load).

While there are 10 files in the bucket I want cloud function to process them in sequential manner i.e 1 file at a time as all the files accesses the same table for operation.

Currently cloud function is getting triggered for multiple files at a time and it fails in BIgquery operation as multiple files trying to access the same table.

Is there any way to configure this in cloud function??

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does all the file write in the same table? If no, can you differentiate the destination table according with a file **prefix** or a different path in GCS? How many files do you have per day?

Comment: Yes, we have a single table to load all the files which is a truncate load table. No, I can't create multiple tables as they will be again pointing to the same final table. 
We receive max 30 files a day but it may vary

Comment: Do the files have a specific order? Or, do you perform a query after your truncate load?

Comment: NO there is no specic order of receiving or loading the files. Yes, we perform our query and transformation activity after staging load.

Comment: Why do you need to process them sequentially?  That complicates cloud architecture, and limits its scalability.  To better understand the issue, read this: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering

Comment: Because my cloud function needs to do truncate and load on same table every time a file comes. My application architecture is as per the link https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions
Please suggest

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, As you identified the issue correctly, I am now trying to use BQ API instead of to_gbq to load my data.

I am trying to use below code from the link
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#loading_a_pandas_dataframe_to_a_table

# to ensure the correct BigQuery data type.
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=[
    bigquery.SchemaField("my_string", "STRING"),
])

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, table_id, job_config=job_config
)

?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using pubsub, and the max instance param on Cloud Function.

- Firstly, use the [notification capability of Google Cloud Storage and sink the event into a PubSub topic](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications).

  - Now you will receive a message every time that a event occur on the bucket. If you want to filter on file creation only (object finalize) you can apply a filter on the subscription. [I wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/pubsub-message-filter-small-feature-for-big-improvements-3d2d690b94a2)
- Then, create an HTTP functions (http function is required if you want to apply a filter) with the [max instance set to 1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances). Like this, only 1 function can be executed in the same time. So, no concurrency!
- Finally, create a PubSub subscription on the topic, with a filter or not, to call your function in HTTP.

**EDIT**

Thanks to your code, I understood what happens. In fact, BigQuery is a declarative system. When you perform a request or a load job, a job is created and it works in background.

In python, you can explicitly wait the end on the job, but, with pandas, I didn't find how!!

I just found a [Google Cloud page to explain how to migrate from pandas to BigQuery client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#loading_a_pandas_dataframe_to_a_table). As you can see, there is a line at the end

```
# Wait for the load job to complete.
job.result()
```

than wait the end of the job.

You did it well in the `_insert_into_bigquery_dwh` function but it's not the case in the staging `_insert_into_bigquery_staging` one. This can lead to 2 issues:

- The dwh function work on the old data because the staging isn't yet finish when you trigger this job
- If the staging take, let's say, 10 seconds and run in "background" (you don't wait the end explicitly in your code) and the dwh take 1 seconds, the next file is processed at the end of the dwh function, even if the staging one continue to run in background. And that leads to your issue.

Comment: Thanks guillaume for your response, but could you please suggest how can I achieve no concurrency when I have implemented the architecture as per https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions

Comment: hmmm, after checking the documentation, you can achieve the same thing. Forget the pubsub and set only the max-instances to the function. It should work as-is.

Comment: Wait, the same cloud function must perform the load AND the query. If not, there isn't consistency because PubSub decouple the process. I mean, if you perform  your query in the streaming_success function, it won't work. Do all in the streaming function.

Comment: Yes, I am doing it all in streaming function. When a file lands into a bucket and cloud function triggers it loads file into a staging table and then performs some query operation and data cleansing and loads in final BQ table. 
But if in the meantime one more lands in the bucket that file also tries to access the same BQ staging table and  it fails the process.
FYI, I have already kept my max instance as 1 in cloud function

Comment: You already have set the max instance to 1 and you have concurrency issue?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Or May be reason is different of two files processing on same table. Do you think so?

Comment: File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py", line 219, in to_gbq    private_key=private_key,  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 1036, in to_gbq    progress_bar=progress_bar,  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 513, in load_data    self.process_http_error(ex)  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 376, in process_http_error    raise GenericGBQException("Reason: {0}".format(ex))pandas_gbq.gbq.GenericGBQException: Reason: 409 Already Exists: Table <My table name>

Comment: This was my error in logs - Cause: Traceback (most recent call last):"

Answer (score 0):

The architecture you describe isn't the same as the one from the documentation you [linked](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions). Note that in the flow diagram and the code samples the storage events triggers the cloud function which will stream the data directly to the destination table. Since BigQuery allow for multiple streaming insert jobs several functions could be executed at the same time without problems. In your use case the intermediate table used to load with write-truncate for data cleaning makes a big difference because each execution needs the previous one to finish thus requiring a sequential processing approach.

I would like to point out that PubSub doesn't allow to configure the rate at which messages are sent, if 10 messages arrive to the topic they all will be sent to the subscriber, even if processed one at a time. Limiting the function to one instance may lead to overhead for the above reason and could increase latency as well. That said, since the expected workload is 15-30 files a day the above maybe isn't a big concern.

If you'd like to have parallel executions you may try creating a new table for each message and set a short expiration deadline for it using `table.expires(exp_datetime)` setter method so that multiple executions don't conflict with each other. Here is the related library [reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table). Otherwise the great answer from Guillaume would completely get the job done.